# CarouselView CarouselPage how to create collection pages with binding items from database? Without MVVM

Tags: android, sqlite, xaml, xamarin

i new to Xamarin, i have DB with this class

```
[Table("Version")] 
public class Version
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement,Column("_Id")]
    public int Version_ID { get; set; }
    public string Version_Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Profile))]               
    public int Version_ProfileID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Version))]               
    public int Version_ParentID { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ParameterValue> Version_ParameterValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to 1 item from class has become 1 page in Carousel without MVVM. (This is not main screen)
That's all I have XAML:

```
 CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
 x:Class="Versions"
 x:Name="LayoutVersions"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}">

<CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Text="{Binding Version_Name}"></Label>
   </DataTemplate>
</CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>
```

And xaml.cs:

```
 public Versions(Categories Category)
    {
        selectedCategory = Category;
        ItemsSource = App.Database7.GetItems(); // it`s line not worked, how to create new page with binding item from database? 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

VersionRepository.cs:

```
    public IEnumerable<Version> GetItems()
    {      
        return database.GetAllWithChildren<Version>(recursive: true);
    }
```

New XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="SniperNote.ListParameters"
         x:Name="LayoutVersions">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <CarouselView x:Name="CarouselVersion">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Version_Name}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

New XAML.cs:

```
 public ListParameters(Categories Category)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectedCategory = Category;
        CarouselVersion.ItemsSource = App.Database7.GetItems();
    }
```

P.S. Sorry for my english, thanks for answers.

Comment: where is the code for `App.Database7.GetItems()`?  Are you sure this is working and returning an IEnumerable?

Comment: Hello, @Jason. I`m added code for App.Database7.GetItems(), thanks for answer. Yes this code return IEnumerable.

Comment: what you have should work.  I would remove the `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` from your XAML, and put `InitializeComponent();` FIRST in your constructor.

Comment: @Jason this line code "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'". ItemsSource Carousel need MultiPage<ContentPage>, function return IEnumerable<Version>.

Comment: CarouselPage has been deprecated in favor of CarouselView, try using that instead

Comment: @Jason I have masterdetail page how main page, carousel is modal page. I can`t navigation to CarousleView.

Comment: replace your CarouselPage with a ContentPage that contains a CarouselView

Comment: @Jason outstanding move with XAML. After `InitializeComponent();`;  Eror: "InitializeComponent()"

XAML:
    <ContentPage.Content> 
        <CarouselView x:Name="CarouselVersion"> <CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Version_Name}"></Label> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
        </CarouselView> 
</ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage>

Comment: A compiler error or a runtime exception?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Jason runtime error `The type initializer for 'Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView' threw an exception.'`

Comment: without seeing your current code it's difficult to say

Comment: What i can to do?

Comment: @Jason take me 2 minutes i editing code in question

Comment: @ Jason I done, thanks for your help

Comment: add this `Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");` before your Forms.Init() call in AppDelegate/MainActivity

Comment: @Jason i find this file in folder with iOS.

Comment: @Jason  error remained.

Comment: are you testing on Android or iOS?  You need to modify in the appropriate file for each platform.  See https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5644

Comment: @Jason i`m developing and testing on Xiami Mi8 Lite (Android 10, API29).

Comment: @Jason Yes, i did for Android and IOS, error remained

Comment: @Jason i seek solution `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");` Thenks you, Jason)

Comment: @Jason but names some versions located on one screen. Carousel not sliding

Comment: does ItemsSource have more than one item?

Comment: @Jason yes, i have 3 test-items in database, instead 3 children carousel i get 3 label on one line without scrolling.